# Using docker-compose in a GitLab CI pipeline

Tags: gitlab, docker-compose, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to implement a GitLab continuous integration (CI) pipeline with the following `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
image: docker:latest

# When using dind, it's wise to use the overlayfs driver for
# improved performance.
variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay

services:
  - docker:dind

before_script:
  - docker info
  - curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.10.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
  - chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
  - export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
  - echo $PATH

stages:
  - build
  - test

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker-compose build
    - docker-compose up -d

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - cd tests/tester
    - pytest test_run_tester.py
  except:
    - /^.*skip_tests$/
```

However, in GitLab I'm getting the following error message:

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.10.4 (b32125f)
Using Docker executor with image docker:latest ...
Starting service docker:dind ...
Pulling docker image docker:dind ...
Waiting for services to be up and running...
Pulling docker image docker:latest ...
Running on runner-2e54fd37-project-13-concurrent-0 via scw-de9c9c...
Fetching changes...
HEAD is now at 2504a08 Update CI config
From https://lab.iperlane.com/gio/ipercron-compose
   2504a08..5c2f23f  CI         -> origin/CI
Checking out 5c2f23f1 as CI...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ docker info
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 0
Server Version: 1.13.1
Storage Driver: overlay
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins: 
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: aa8187dbd3b7ad67d8e5e3a15115d3eef43a7ed1
runc version: 9df8b306d01f59d3a8029be411de015b7304dd8f
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.8.14-docker-2
Operating System: Alpine Linux v3.5 (containerized)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 7.751 GiB
Name: 90395a030c02
ID: 7TKR:5PQN:XLFM:EJST:NF2V:NLQC:I2IZ:6OZG:TR4U:ZEAK:EVXE:HIF7
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled
$ curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.10.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100   600    0   600    0     0   1175      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1176

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
  3 7929k    3  254k    0     0   116k      0  0:01:08  0:00:02  0:01:06  258k
 17 7929k   17 1358k    0     0   433k      0  0:00:18  0:00:03  0:00:15  704k
 61 7929k   61 4861k    0     0  1164k      0  0:00:06  0:00:04  0:00:02 1636k
100 7929k  100 7929k    0     0  1703k      0  0:00:04  0:00:04 --:--:-- 2300k
$ chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
$ export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
$ docker-compose build
/bin/sh: eval: line 51: docker-compose: not found
ERROR: Build failed: exit code 127
```

The system seems not to be able to find `docker-compose`, even after installing it and adding it to the path. Is there perhaps another image such that `docker-compose` commands can be made, or a different way to install it in the `.gitlab-ci.yml`?

Comment: Have you tried setting an absolute path to `docker-compose`?

Comment: @Kurt Peek: 
What of the three Setup types did you use:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#runner-configuration

Comment: This question is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868369/run-docker-compose-build-in-gitlab-ci-yml/41455005#41455005

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### The problem

This is complex problem.

The `docker:latest` image is based on `alpine` ([Alpine Linux](https://alpinelinux.org/)), which is built using [`musl-libc`](https://www.musl-libc.org/). This system is very barebones, and as such doesn't have everything a full-fledged desktop Linux might have. In fact, dynamic executables need to be compiled specifically for this system.

`docker-compose` is a Python application, bundled into a Linux executable using PyInstaller. These executables are really only expected to be able to run on the system which they were built. If you run an `alpine` container, and `apk add file`, you can see that the (dynamically-linked) executable you downloaded is expecting a specific interpreter.

```
# file /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
/usr/local/bin/docker-compose.pyinstaller: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=00747fe5bcde089bb4c2f1ba7ab5348bc02ac5bf, stripped
```

The problem is `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` doesn't exist in `alpine`. In fact, `/lib64` doesn't even exist.

#### The solution

Because `docker-compose` is a Python application, it [can also be installed using `pip`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/#/install-using-pip):

Testing this inside an `alpine` container:

```
$ docker run --rm -it alpine /bin/bash
```

Here are the commands you can run manually, or add to your `.gitlab-ci.yml` `before_script`:

```
# apk add --no-cache python py2-pip
...
# pip install --no-cache-dir docker-compose
...
# docker-compose -v
docker-compose version 1.11.1, build 7c5d5e4
```

---

It turns out there is actually an open issue for this:

- https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3465

Comment: Great explanation. I created a simple docker image to shave off precious time from the install process. See https://hub.docker.com/r/tmaier/docker-compose/

Answer (score 19):

Docker-compose is now an [official image](https://hub.docker.com/r/docker/compose). You can put

```
image: 
  name: docker/compose:1.23.2
  entrypoint: [""]
```

at the top of your `.gitlab-ci.yml`. You need to remove the default entrypoint of the compose image, which is done by the second line. After that, you can use both `docker` and `docker-compose`.

This works per GitLab 9.4. You can also build a custom image

```
FROM docker/compose:1.23.2
ENTRYPOINT []
```

and use it as your image.

Comment: This doesn't appear to start the docker daemon, resulting in `docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))`.

Comment: That is correct. Using a docker image (or derived images like compose) will only supply the docker command line utility. You still need to set up the docker daemon, which is usually done by having `docker:dind` (docker-in-docker) as a service. Your job then connects to the daemon running in another container (but within the same network).
I was playing around with our setup, but I could not reproduce your exact error.

Comment: 2022 Update: it's abandoned, but as per other answer, the main `docker` image now has `docker-compose` (newer versions)

Answer (score 3):

The [docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker) Docker image now has docker-compose preinstalled.

It can be pulled to your local machine simply with `docker pull docker`.

It can be used in GitLab CI like this:

```yaml
my_job:
  stage: my_stage
  image: docker
  script:
    - docker-compose up
```

It is based on [Alpine Linux](https://www.alpinelinux.org), so [apk commands](https://docs.alpinelinux.org/user-handbook/0.1a/Working/apk.html) are the order of the day. It comes with /bin/sh preinstalled.

Answer (score 0):

I was fighting with this few days. Finally I found and tested solution:
https://hub.docker.com/r/tmaier/docker-compose/ with open source code: https://github.com/tmaier/docker-compose.

Below is sample from [source above](https://github.com/tmaier/docker-compose):

```
image: tmaier/docker-compose:latest

services:
  - docker:dind

before_script:
  - docker info
  - docker-compose --version

build image:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker-compose build
```

and everything is working (no need to set up extra Docker-in-Docker). The only disadvantage is that it is not verified publisher in hub.docker.com.