# docker-compose throws error with gitlab-ci

Tags: docker-compose, gitlab

I try to use **Gitlab CI** with **docker-compose** but I always get this error :

```
$ docker-compose up -d --build
Creating network "backoffice_default" with the default driver
Building php
Creating backoffice_database_1 ... 
Creating backoffice_database_1 ... done
Creating backoffice_php_1 ... 
Creating backoffice_php_1 ... done

$ docker-compose exec php composer -v
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/docker-compose", line 6, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 68, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 121, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 464, in exec_command
  File "site-packages/dockerpty/pty.py", line 338, in start
  File "site-packages/dockerpty/io.py", line 32, in set_blocking
ValueError: file descriptor cannot be a negative integer (-1)
Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

I use docker with `shell` runner, as follows :

```
[[runners]]
  name = "direct runner"
  url = MY_GITLAB_URL
  token = REPO_GITLAB_TOKEN
  executor = "shell"
  [runners.cache]
```

Here's my `docker-compose.yml` file :

```
version: '2'

services:

  database:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: database
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysql_strong_password
      MYSQL_USER: database
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: mysql_strong_password

  php:
    build: ./app/docker
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./app/docker/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini
      - ./:/var/www/symfony
    links:
      - database
```

And here's my `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
stages:
- build
- cleanup_build
- test
- deploy
- cleanup

before_script:
- docker info

build:
  stage: build
  script:
  - docker-compose up -d --build
  - docker-compose exec php composer -v
  - docker-compose exec php composer install
  - docker-compose exec php php bin/console doctrine:schema:create --dump-sql --force
  - docker-compose exec php php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load -n

cleanup_build:
  stage: cleanup_build
  script:
  - docker-compose config
  - docker-compose ps
  - docker-compose logs php
  - docker-compose logs database
  - exit 1
  when: on_failure

phpunit:
  stage: test
  script:
  - docker-compose exec -T php phpunit -c .

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - echo "deploy to staging server"

cleanup:
  stage: cleanup
  script:
  - docker-compose down
```

Do you guys have any idea on how to resolve this ?
Because I tried directly from shell using `gitlab-runner` user and executing the same cmds i didn't have any error. I tried to run the `docker-compose exec` with the `-T` flag and there is another error : `ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1` with no additionnal message

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868369/run-docker-compose-build-in-gitlab-ci-yml) question help me find how to solve that problem.

Simply adding a `-T` arg after the exec helped tremendously