# How to install docker-compose along with openjdk in gitlab-ci file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a spring boot application I want to test via `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

It's set up already like this:

```yaml
image: openjdk:12

# services:
#   - docker:dind

stages:
  - build

before_script:
#  - apk add --update python py-pip python-dev && pip install docker-compose
#  - docker version
#  - docker-compose version
  - chmod +x mvnw

build:
  stage: build
  script:
#    - docker-compose up -d
    - ./mvnw package
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/rest-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

The commented out portions are from the answer to [Run docker-compose build in .gitlab-ci.yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868369/run-docker-compose-build-in-gitlab-ci-yml) which I noticed has a fully distinct docker image.

Obviously I need java installed to run my spring boot application, so does that mean docker is just not an option?