# Gitlab pipeline for running tests for java app depending on other services

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab-ci, cicd

I have a spring boot app which is an movies API. In order to run my integrated tests I need mongodb and rabbitmq up and running and other services included in a docker-compose file.

docker-compose-test.yml:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  gateway-app:
    image: 'danielmarandici/movies_gateway:tagname'
    ports:
      - "8088:8088"
    environment:
      eureka.instance.preferIpAddress: 'true'
      eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone: http://eurekaserver:8761/eureka/
      eureka.host: eurekaserver
    networks:
      - ms-network
  eurekaserver:
    image: 'danielmarandici/eureka_server:tagname'
    environment:
      eureka.client.registerWithEureka: 'false'
      eureka.client.fetchRegistry: 'false'
      eureka.instance.preferIpAddress: 'true'
      eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone: http://eurekaserver:8761/eureka/
    ports:
      - 8761:8761
    networks:
      - ms-network
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    networks:
      - ms-network
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.10.7-management
    hostname: rabbitmq
    restart: always
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=rmuser
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=rmpassword
      - RABBITMQ_SERVER_ADDITIONAL_ERL_ARGS=-rabbit log_levels [{connection,error},{default,error}] disk_free_limit 2147483648
    volumes:
      - ~/volumes/cnas/rabbitmq:/var/lib/rabbitmq
    ports:
      - '15673:15673'
      - '5672:5672'
    networks:
      - ms-network

networks:
  ms-network:
    driver: bridge
```

here is the .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
variables:
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "--batch-mode --errors --fail-at-end --show-version"

stages:
  - build
  - build_and_test
  # - startneed
  # - test

build:
  image: maven:latest
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS compile


# startneed:
#   image: docker/compose:latest
#   services:
#     - docker:dind
#   stage: startneed
#   script:
#     - docker-compose -f docker-compose-test.yml up -d

# test:
#   image: maven:latest
#   stage: test
#   script:
#     - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS test

before_script:
  - apt-get update
  - apt-get install -y docker.io docker-compose

build_and_test:
  stage: build_and_test
  image: maven:latest
  script:
    - echo "Running Docker Compose services..."
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose-test.yml up -d
    - echo "Running Maven tests..."
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS test
    - echo "Stopping Docker Compose services..."
    - docker-compose down
```

I have tried and the commented jobs but still didnt work. Here is the error i get:

```
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose-test.yml up -d
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 700, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 395, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1283, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1329, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1278, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1038, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 976, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 30, in connect
    sock.connect(self.unix_socket)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 756, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 532, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/six.py", line 718, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 700, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
....

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 152, in get_project
    client = get_client(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 41, in get_client
    client = docker_client(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 170, in docker_client
    client = APIClient(use_ssh_client=not use_paramiko_ssh, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 197, in __init__
    self._version = self._retrieve_server_version()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 221, in _retrieve_server_version
    raise DockerException(
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I have tried several approaches but no success. Is there a possible solution for this? To run a docker-compose command and after to execute a mvn command. (I am a novice to writing pipelines).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run docker-compose build in .gitlab-ci.yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868369/run-docker-compose-build-in-gitlab-ci-yml)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are just lacking the permissions to run the docker commands.

Try with

```
sudo docker ps -a
```

to see if it works.

If that is the case, add your user to the docker group

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

and reboot the system. Now it should work.